# Discord.py Editing private message for 1 user edits it for everyone issue

Tags: python, discord.py

I have a discord bot that you can private message. One of the commands makes the bot send you a message and then uses bot.wait_for to wait for the user to answer the message and once they do it will edit the initial message it sent you and change the text to something else. This works but if 2 users message the bot and both are waiting on the bot.wait_for and 1 person replies to the message the bot edits the message for both peoples private message even if the other user never replied to it.

How do i get it to only edit the message for the user who replied to the bot?

Here is some of my code:

```
testMessage = await context.send(embed=discord.Embed(title="Message Title", description="Message Text", color=0x42F56C))

wait = await bot.wait_for('message',)
await testMessage.edit(embed=discord.Embed(title="NEW Message Title", description="NEW Message Text", color=0x42F56C))
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a check for this:

```py
wait = await bot.wait_for('message', check=lambda message: message.author == ctx.author)
```

Then it will wait for message from a certain user (author of the first message).

Comment: Yeah that fixed it thanks i was looking in the documentation must of missed the check part.